# Allow only specific words within URL by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I searched the entire of stack overflow but was unable to figure out this.

I want allow only specific words within URL by htaccess with an exception.

E.g: All URLs with none of these words: (big, red, dark) to return 404 error unless there is a `&` in URL.

examples:

e.g1:

`http://www.example.com/7big6556/` Allowed

e.g2:

`http://www.example.com/8green65533` Return 404

e.g3:

`http://www.example.com/hi-green&nice` Allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come with solution:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*\/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !big
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !red
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dark
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\&
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,R=404]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !big|red|dark [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Comment: how about the exception?

Comment: This not works, returns 404 for these words. It should allow these words not 404

Comment: @smith the rewriteCond is negitive, it allows these 3words in uri and returns 404 if the requested uri does not contain one of these 3 words

Comment: It allows /foobig and returns 404 for /foobar